# 2d animation export only keyframes

Tags: export, keyframes

How to render only those 4 keyframes (just an example real test has more keyframes)
Sketch_0001.png; Sketch_0014.png; Sketch_0022.png; Sketch_0030.png;

[image: https://i.imgur.com/gnSwvUg.png]

Comment: Probably the quickest way is to set your frame range from frame 1 to frame 30 as png images, then go to the output folder/directory and delete all those not required. (delete in groups) - OR - set the frame range from and to frame 1, render that out and do the same with the other 3.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am doint now. 
Thing is- there will by a lot of files- more like 2000 to delete. And they will differ visually only slightly.

I can delete using ImageMagick but thought I can skip this step natively in Blender

Comment: I'd consider checking out the [Loom Addon](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom), it's perfectly suited for this. Specifically the "render specific keyframes" under the "Options" should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks,  Xylvier !That does look like exactly what I need. Sadly I do get "Nothing Selected" error. Have tried multiple blender versions. What am I doing wrong? https://i.imgur.com/wlhsqAn.png

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for suggestions. Workflow that sorts of work for me is as follow:

Once You have the grease pencil animation that You like:
[image]

[Loom Addon](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom)
Sadly it does not detect grease pencil keyframes. Thus it is needed to create object level keyframes. Empty will do fine. Create one and paste them on frames where Grease pencil keyframes are.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/PEOsrWT.gif]

Select all keyframes (in Dope Sheet) You want and choose "Render Selected Keyframes"
[image]

It then creates the keyframes list:
[image]

And finally it creates animation from keyframes only:
[image]

Comment: Loom addon was updated with proper grease pencil support.